# glViewport offset and ortho projection

Tags: opengl, c++

In all tutorials I found about creating projection matrix based on viewport size all of them assumed that left bottom coordinates of viewport will be (0,0).

Now I want to draw to the different parts of the screen and for that purpose I want to switch viewports accordingly:

```
glViewport(0,0,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2); //left bottom
glViewport(0,windowHeight/2,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//left top
glViewport(windowWidth/2,0,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//right bottom
glViewport(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//right top
```

Now I have a problem with defining my projection matrix. Without having any (x,y) offest I was using this code for calculating my ortho projection matrix:

```
float m_fWindowSize = 15.0f;

if (m_WindowWidth > m_WindowHeight)
{
    auto viewportAspectRatio = (float)m_WindowWidth / (float)m_WindowHeight;

    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fLeft = (-1.0f) * m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fRight = m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fBottom = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fTop = m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fNear = -(10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fFar = (10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;

    m_fMoveSpeed = static_cast<GLfloat>(m_fWindowSize * 2 / static_cast<float>(m_WindowHeight));
}
else
{
    auto viewportAspectRatio = (float)m_WindowHeight / (float)m_WindowWidth;

    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fLeft = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fRight = m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fBottom = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fTop = m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fNear = -(10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fFar = (10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;

    m_fMoveSpeed = static_cast<GLfloat>(m_fWindowSize * 2 / static_cast<float>(m_WindowWidth));
}
```

And this works fine UNTIL I will add any (x,y) offset to my viewport. The effect is following when using `glViewport(0, m_WindowHeight/2,  m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)`:

[image: glViewport(0, m_WindowHeight/2, m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)]

And with `glViewport(0, 0,  m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)`: 
[image: glViewport(0, 0, m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)]

**So how I can change projection matrix accordingly to the viewport offset?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your projection matrix accordingly to the viewport.

Have you considered to render the scene to a fbo and then render the fbo fullscreen (from -1, -1 to 1, 1) with `glViewport(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2, height / 2)`? This will took a quarter of the screen (top right).

In my current project, i can freely set the offset of `glViewport` without any problem and without changing my projection matrix. So i suppose the problem lies in your projection matrix or somewhere else.

Edit: On second thought, i just realize you didn't set up the matrix manually. Well that's harder for me.. *lol*. By the way, the person answering your question on StackOverflow is right, aspect ratio is `width / height`. Probably not going to fix your problem, but good to know.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning drawng to the framebuffer. I was already doing that and glViewport() accumulation caused the whole issue

Comment: @Amadeusz Glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my problem: **I have to set the viewport to begin at origin when I render to framebuffer**.

I didn't mentioned that I was rendering my scene to the framebuffer, because I thought it was irrelevant and apparently that casued the problem.

In my case viewport transfromations accumulated: first when rendering to texture using framebuffer and second time when rendering this texture to screen.

So the result was that when I set offset in glViewport() as windowWidth/2 or windowHeight/2 my whole texture was shifted by windowWidth or windowHeight and rendered outside the screen.

What I had to do in my rendering pipeline was basicly that:

```
glViewport(0,0,windowWidth, windowHeight);
//*************************
//render stuff to the framebuffer
//*************************
glViewport(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
```

And the effect is as expected:
[image: Success!!!]